# adding information to child->child LINKED LIST

Tags: c, linked-list

So I am trying to do a program with multiples child that those ones contains multiple child inside them, for example :

```
root = NULL.

-root->child  (this one contain the first file name)
--root->child->child  (this one contain the information inside the file)
-root->child  (second file name)
--root->child->child  (second file information)
```

So my main problem is putting the right information inside the child.

So I am wondering if the way I am doing it goes with the good logic or I should start from 0 again.

this is my structure :

```
typedef struct      s_lst
{
    char            *content; //path name 
    int             data;     //path number
    struct s_lst    *next;
    struct s_lst    *child;
}                   t_lst;
```

this is my code :

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    t_lst *root;
    root = NULL;
    root = new_node(0,0);
    add_child(root, "first-child", 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        lst_add(&(root)->child->child, new_node("inside first child child", i));
    add_child(root, "second", 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        lst_add(&(root)->child->child, new_node("inside second child child", i));
    ft_print(root);
}

t_lst   *new_node(char *name, int data)
{
    t_lst *new_node;

    if (!(new_node = malloc(sizeof(t_lst))))
        return (0);
    new_node->content = name;
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    new_node->child = NULL;
    return (new_node);
}

t_lst   *add_sibling(t_lst *n, char *name, int data)
{
    if (n == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    while (n->next)
        n = n->next;
    return (n->next = new_node(name, data));
}

t_lst   *add_child(t_lst *n, char *name, int data)
{
    if (n == NULL)
        return (NULL);

    if (n->child)
        return (add_sibling(n->child, name, data));
    else
        return (n->child = new_node(name, data));
}

void    lst_add(t_lst **head, t_lst *new)
{
    t_lst   *tmp;

    if (*head)
    {
        tmp = *head;
        while (tmp->next)
            tmp = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = new;
    }
    else
        *head = new;
}
```

ft_print :

```
void    ft_print(t_lst *root)
{
    while (root)
    {
        while (root->child)
        {
            printf("%s\n", root->child->content);
            printf("-----------------------------\n");
            while (root->child->child)
            {
                printf("node->child->child %s\n", root->child->child->content);
                root->child->child = root->child->child->next;
            }
            printf("\n");
            root->child = root->child->next;
        }
        root = root->next;
    }
}
```

also an image as example : 
[here is an example what i am trying to do. As you can see the second "text" goes into my first child.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKeJo.png)
thanks for your help, having a hard time learning linked list :D!

Comment: where is the definition of function: `ft_print()`?

Comment: when the parameters to `main(0` are not being used, then should use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `if (!(new_node = malloc(sizeof(t_lst))))
        return (0);`  when the call to `malloc()` fails, then a NULL pointer is returned to `main()`.  However, `main()` fails to check for that condition,  This will lead to a seg fault event.  Much better to use: `if (!(new_node = malloc(sizeof(t_lst)))) { perror( "malloc failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }` so the program exits rather than trying to continue with an unrecoverable error. The call to `perror()` also enables the error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to be output to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `t_lst   *new_node(char *name, int data)
{
    t_lst *new_node;` it is  a very poor programming practice to have some local variable in a function be the same name as the name of the function.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem, so we can help you debug it.,  Especially show what the problem is with the child

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help and tips. I update my post with more explanation and a picture as example.

Comment: `new_node->content = name;` is only working by happy accident that you are passing *string literals*, but won't work for `0`. Since `new_node->content` is type `char*`, you must assign the address for a valid block of memory (which is generally done by allocating, copying to the new block, and then assigning, but it can point to the address of a *string literal*, but not to the address of `0`, though it can be `NULL`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks man, I just use strdup now to allocate the memory and in case is NULL, i just set it to NULL.

`if (name == NULL)
  new_node->content = NULL;
 else
  new_node->content = strdup(name);`

Comment: That's a solid approach. Remember, since `strdup` allocates, you should *validate*, e.g. `new_node->content = strdup(name); if (!new_node->content) { /* handle error */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that in your second loop you are adding into the same (first) child:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    lst_add(&(root)->child->child, new_node("inside second child child", i));
//                        ^~~~~~~
//              should be ->next->child here
```

Better yet would be to take advantage of the return values of `add_child` which will make the logic a lot more clear:

```
t_lst *first_child = add_child(root, "first-child", 0);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    lst_add(&first_child->child, new_node("inside first child child", i));

t_lst *second_child = add_child(root, "second-child", 0);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    lst_add(&second_child->child, new_node("inside second child child", i));
```

The other problem which you've not discovered **yet** is that you are modifying your lists in your `ft_print` function:

```
void ft_print(t_lst *root)
{
    while (root)
    {
        while (root->child)
        {
            ...
            while (root->child->child)
            {
                ...
                root->child->child = root->child->child->next;
                // reassigning and effectively "loosing" child nodes here
            }
            ...
            root->child = root->child->next;
            // and here
        }
        root = root->next;
    }
}
```

You should use local variables for iterating through child nodes instead:

```
t_lst *current = root->child;
while (current)
{
    ...
    current = current->next;
}
```

Comment: Hey!

Thanks for your help man, I just found and i am going to start using local variables :D it has more logic and easy to use :)!